# Check if select option selected

Tags: php, forms, select

I have a form where I post some options to a mysql query. When it returns, it a draw a table with some data.

How to set the select box's option to be selected if my form returned?

I tried this, but not working:

```
<form method="post" id="partnersearchform">
<input type="hidden" name="formaction" value="partnersearch">
Partner Típus<br>
<select onchange="document.getElementById('partnersearchform').submit();" size="" name="ceg">
<option value="">(mind)</option>
<option value="1" if($ceg==1){ print 'selected'; }>Magánszemélyek</option>
<option value="2" if($ceg==2){ print 'selected'; }>Cégek</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to open and close php tags:

```
<form method="post" id="partnersearchform">
<input type="hidden" name="formaction" value="partnersearch">
Partner Típus<br>
<select onchange="document.getElementById('partnersearchform').submit();" size="" name="ceg">
<option value="">(mind)</option>
<option value="1"<?php if($ceg==1){ print ' selected'; }?>>Magánszemélyek</option>
<option value="2"<?php if($ceg==2){ print ' selected'; }?>>Cégek</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
<?php if($ceg==1){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>
```

Also make sure what you get in $ceg var.

```
<option value="<?php echo $ceg;?>"
 <?php if($ceg==1){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }?>>Magánszemélyek</option>
```

Comment: I don't think the option value needs to be $ceg.. that's just one value.. and there are multiple options.. $cev is the variable he is comparing the values to

Comment: No but I thought jut that he can debug $ceg to see if problem is that he is getting  something that he is not expecting in $ceg as well as mistake in php open and close :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="1" <?php if($ceg==1){ print 'selected'; }?> >Magánszemélyek</option>
```